# unable to get 'while True' conditions to work

Tags: python, while-loop, break

I'm trying to make a code that can generate valid credit card numbers. So far I've created the random number generator that adds a specific prefix in front of it (in this case, I'm using Visa's prefix '4' and generating an additional 15 random integers behind it). The problem I think I'm having is I am unable to get my 'while True' conditions to work.

As it stands, when I run the program, it prints a seemingly arbitrary amount of 16 digit numbers that do start with '4', but don't follow the algorithm I have set up in my 'while True' conditions. Some of the numbers this code prints is valid when copied and pasted here:

https://www.dcode.fr/luhn-algorithm

The majority do not, however.

I have used the portion of the code that confirms the Luhn's algorithm works with success on another project, but for some reason I can't get it to work here. Any guidance is greatly appreciated as I'm very new to Python.
This is what I have done so far...

```
import random

    def s():
        prefix = '4'
        return (prefix + str(random.randint(100000000000000,999999999999999)))

    while True:
        print(s())
        q_16= (2*int(s()[14]),2*int(s()[12]),2*int(s()[10]),2*int(s()[8]),2*int(s()[6]),2*int(s()[4]),2*int(s()[2]),2*int(s()[0]))
        p= int("".join(map(str, q_16)))
        p2= list(map(int, str(p)))
        p3= sum(p2)+int(s()[15])+int(s()[13])+int(s()[11])+int(s()[9])+int(s()[7])+int(s()[5])+int(s()[3])+int(s()[1])
        if p3 % 10 == 0:
            break
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand Luhn's algorithm, but I don't think you should be generating a new random number for every single digit that you check.  Put the result of `s()` in a variable.

Comment: Maybe this is where I am confused. When I take the results of s() and put it into a variable and run it, I either get one of two things. I'll get a correct output if I run it enough times, or I'll get an incorrect output that prints infinitely, also ignoring the conditions in my if statement.

Comment: Do you create the variable inside or outside of the loop?  If you create it outside, you will be checking the same string over and over, so your `if p3 % 10 == 0` will always have the same result.  It will either `break` immediately if you get lucky, or it will loop forever because `p3` never changes from that point on.  You want to run `s()` *once* per iteration of the loop.

Comment: That did it! Thank you!